# Hosting plain old HTML from Java site

Tags: java, html

I have created a simple webservice based on RestExpress that returns a list of json objects. Works great. (Big fan of RestExpress) Now, I have a simple HTML page using jquery and angularjs to build a grid based on these results. I would like to include this page in my site so it can be easily deployed as one unit. I have a route that works but am stuck at this point. However, I am at a loss at how to do this and am obviously asking the wrong questions of the google machine to get where I need to go.

I have come from a C#/.NET background so I'm sure if I can just be pointed to the correct libraries to use, I can figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to host your page using a webserver which really has nothing to do with java such as apache webserver see http://httpd.apache.org/

If you are actually trying to host more complicated things with java behind the scenes than just an html/javascript page you may need an server that can server jsp such as tomcat or a java application server such as glassfish, jboss, websphere. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_application_servers. You would then need to package your application as a war and deploy it to the server.